# How can I preform calculations on mongodb

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, find, mongodb-query

I have an assignment for school related to databases. We choose to operate using `MongoDB and python 2.7` for technical reasons. We consider to have this data in the DB.

```
data=[{"name":"zack","age": '12'},\
      {"name":"jake","age": '13'},\
      {"name":"drake","age": '14'},\
      {"name":"mike","age": '15'}]
```

Once we inserted the data to the collection, we wanted to do calculations on the kids ages in a manner of loop of course so we ran this:

```
 for kid in t.find({},{'_id':False,'name':False}):
    print 5+int(kid)`
```

And the output was

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\...\school_project.py", line 17, in <module>
    print 5+int(kid)
    TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

When we tried to attach a string to the kids name like as `"hello" + kid + "how are you?"` and ended up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\...\school_project.py", line 17,...
print "hello" + kid + "how are you?"
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects
```

I want my query to return me integer/string objects and not `dict`.

So I figure, we might query the wrong way, is there a 'right' way for us to use the data that i stored into the DB and insert it into an `int\string` variable?

Or is it just how MongoDB is?

Comment: The output from MongoDB will be in dict format which will contain name,age ,id as key

Comment: You should try print 5+int(kid["age"])

Comment: For printing you may try print "hello" + kid["name"] + "how are you?"

Comment: yes , i'm aware of that, is there a way to use the values in the 'dict' fields in a variable? or maybe there is another way of query?

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method returns a document (`dict`) and not a value. So make sure you extract the field you want from the `dict` before applying `int` to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes:**

```
 print 5+int(kid["age"])
```

Since the output from mongo will be in dict[JSON] format you have to query the particular element and then add

```
print "hello" + kid["name"] + "how are you?"
```

Will give the kids name with hello world